# simulation of genetic data in R

Tags: r, simulation, genetics

I am looking for the best way or best package available for simulating a genetic association between a specific SNP and a quantitative phenotype, with the simulated data being the most similar to my real data, except that I know the causal variant. 
All of the packages I saw in R seem to be specialised in pedigree data or in population data where coalescence and other evolutionary factors are specified, but I don't have any experience in population genetics and I only want to simulate the simple case of European 
population with a similar characteristics to my real data 
(i.e. normal distribution for the trait and an additive effect for the genotype, similar allele frequancies…)
So for example if my genetic data is X and my quantitative variable is Y:

```
X <-rbinom(1000,2,0.4)
Y <- rnorm(1000,1,0.4)
```

I am looking for something in R similar to the function in Plink where one needs to specify a range of allele frequencies, a range for the phenotype, and specify a specific variant which should result associated with the genotype (this is important because I need to repeat these associations in different datasets with the causal variant being the same)

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Also have a look at this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/simulate-data-for-power-analysis-of-logistic-regresion-model-include-covarianc

Answer (score 1):

If the genotype changes only the mean of the phenotype, this is very simple.

```
phenotype.means <- c(5, 15, 20)  # phenotype means for genotypes 0, 1, and 2
phenotype.sd <- 5
X <- rbinom(1000,2,0.4)
Y <- rnorm(1000, phenotype.means[X], phenotype.sd)
```

This will lead to `Y` containing 1000 normally distributed variables, where those with homozygous recessive genotypes (`aa`, or 0) will have a mean of 5, those with heterozyous genotypes (`Aa`, or 1) will have a mean of 15, and those with homozygous dominant genotypes (`AA`, or 2) will have a mean of 20.

If you want a more traditional 2 setting phenotype (`AA/Aa` versus `aa`), just set `phenotype.means` to something like `c(5, 20, 20)`.

Comment: Thank you David for your suggestion. I might have oversimplified my real data, I am looking for a way to model my real data closely, so I would like to be able to reproduce the same allele frequencies as are in my data, and I really need to be able to control the specific variant that results associated because I will then need to associate this same variant using another dataset… Is this confusing? thank you again for your help

Comment: You're welcome. If (and only if) this fully answers your question, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Hi David, I posted a similar question in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/463952/simulate-normal-distributed-real-data-phenotypes-from-genotypic-data-in-r. Maybe you could have an idea of this. Thank you in advance.